# Android Studio toolbar is not at top of the page

Tags: android-studio, android-toolbar, android-constraintlayout

Toolbar is at the top of the page on Android studio but on runtime there occurs a blank part as if there is a marginTop attribute. I want the toolbar to be at the top.

here is my code (there are no codes in main.kt or in any other .kt file):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/spt_fp_scrollview"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".grammar.viewpager.screens.FirstFragment"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/spt_fp_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/spt_fp_next"
        android:layout_width="52dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_navigate_next_24"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/spt_fp_toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/spt_fp_toolbar" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/spt_fp_toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/spt_fp_toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/spt_fp_toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/spt_fp_toolbar"
        android:text="Simple Present Tense  1/6"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_one"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@string/font_family"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/spt_fp_1"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/spt_fp_toolbar" />
```

[image: Android studio view][image: The view on runtime (on my phone)]

These are the codes in themes.xml / themes.xml (night) that I used to remove the action bar (Other than these two lines of codes, I didn't change anything on the themes file):

```xml
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Comment: set constraint layout's height = match_parent instead of wrap_content

Comment: I tried to do that but it didn't work unfortunately